# Using tensorflow with VERBS support without infiniband device

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, infiniband, rdma

I am interested in the RDMA support in tensorflow 1.15 for workers and parameter servers to communicate directly without going through CPU. I do not have infiniband VERBS devices but can build tensorflow from source with VERBS support

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --config=verbs //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

after `sudo yum install libibverbs-devel` on centos-7. However, after pip installing the built package via

```
./bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg && pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl,
```

my training failed with the following error:

```
F tensorflow/contrib/verbs/rdma.cc:127] Check failed: dev_list No InfiniBand device found
```

This is expected since I do not have infiniband hardware on my machine. But **do I really need infiniband if my job is run not cross-machine, but on a single machine**? I just want to test whether RDMA can significantly speed up parameter server-based training. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't RDMA.  If you are transferring data from one GPU memory to another GPU memory in the same machine, GPUDirect RDMA is not involved.  Neither is infiniband.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Do you know of any framework that supports arbitrary GPU memory to GPU memory transfer, that's more flexible than that offered by NCCL?

Comment: NCCL is a collectives library. If you are doing collective operations, it should be pretty good and is included in most DL frameworks.  For arbitrary communications, I would imagine you would just use GPUDirect P2P directly, or else CUDA IPC.  I don't have specific recipes or instructions.

Answer (score 2):

> But do I really need Infiniband if my job is run not cross-machine, but on a single machine?

No and it seems you misunderstand what [RDMA actually is](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect). RDMA ("GPUDirect") is a way for third party devices like network interfaces and storage adapters to directly write to a GPUs memory across the PCI bus. It is intended for improved multi-node performance in things like compute clusters. It has nothing to do with multi-GPU operations within in a single node ("peer-to-peer"), where GPUs connected to one node can directly access one another's memory without trips to the host CPU.